# How do you set the keychain's access to be kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Googled but can't find anything on how to set this attribute for the keychain in swift.
There's a few bits and pieces about it with Obj-C, but trying to find a correspondence between Swift usage of the keychain and Obj-C is bloddy impossible almost.

I've got some existing code (from the Realm Swift documentation) to set an encryption key, but want to set the access from the default to kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock.

```
class func getKey() -> NSData {
    let keychainIdentifier = "Realm.EncryptionKey"
    let keychainIdentifierData = keychainIdentifier.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    // First check in the keychain for an existing key
    var query: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: keychainIdentifierData as AnyObject,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 512 as AnyObject,
        kSecReturnData: true as AnyObject
    ]


    var dataTypeRef: AnyObject?
    var status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &dataTypeRef) { SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0)) }
    if status == errSecSuccess {
        return dataTypeRef as! NSData
    }

    // No pre-existing key from this application, so generate a new one
    let keyData = NSMutableData(length: 64)!
    let result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, keyData.mutableBytes.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 64))
    assert(result == 0, "Failed to get random bytes")

    // Store the key in the keychain
    query = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: keychainIdentifierData as AnyObject,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 512 as AnyObject,
        kSecValueData: keyData
    ]

    status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)

    return keyData
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` to the query dictionary you use to add the key.

If you want to update the accessibility status after its already been added, you need to specify the `kSecValueData` and `kSecAttrAccessible` keys in the dictionary you pass to `SecItemUpdate`.

Comment: This saved me hours of headbanging (and I grant you Metallica aren't involved)